# Best Practices to use services in Spring Controller

Tags: spring, controller

So, I have Spring Controller For User Entity,
Structure is as below

```
UserController
UserService
UserRepository

AddressService
AddressRepository
```

My question is, lets say for user operations, I have UserController and UserService for all business logic. Now, lets say, UserService alone is not sufficient to get the data/or prepare the results. So, I'll required another service. e.g AddressService. So, my question is should I inject it in Service class or Controller?

Lets say i want to fetch the Addresses of User by user Id, then should I just Inject AddressService in UserController and fetch the addresses? Or delegate call to UserService and from UserService call AddressService method to fetch the addresses. So the bussiness object will hold the responsibility to fetch the user specific data.

Just, trying to understand the best practices.

Comment: Well, you inject it inthe controller, in order to be able to use it. What exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is, lets say for user operations, I have UserController and UserService for all business logic. Now, lets say, UserService alone is not sufficient to get the data/or prepare the results. So, I'll required another service. e.g AddressService. So, my question is should I inject it in Service class or Controller?